# Как задавать длину 2-мерного массива выбранной пользователем длиной

Tags: c++, массивы

Для одномерных массивов подходит такой вариант:

```
int size;
    cout << "Введите длину массива" << endl;
    cin >> size;
int* mass = new int[size];
```

А как сделать у двумерного и т.д.?

Answer (score 3):

В цикле:

```
 int x, y;
 cout << "Введите длинну массива" << endl;
 cin >> x >> y;
 int** mass = new int*[x];
 for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i) mass[i] = new int[y];
```

Answer (score 2):

Советую юзать vector вместо массивов.

```
int n=5,m=6; //n - кол-во строк, m - кол-во столбцов
vector<vector<int>> v(n);
for (auto& e: v)
       e.resize(m);
//обход вектора таким образом
for (int i = 0;i<n;++i)
       for (int j = 0;j<m;++j)
              v[i][j] = i+j;
 //или так
 for (auto& e:v)
        for (auto& a:e)
               a = 0;
```

Comment: Вопрос всё же не о том, что лучше. Тем более вектор дает лишний оверхед.

Comment: Возможностей тоже больше